# An example of a divergent function that is bounded and continuously differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show that the function $f(x)=(-1)^x$ is such a function. Is it sufficient to show that the limit of two subsequences of $x$ are not equal (i.e. $1$, $-1$)?

Comment: You'll run into trouble when $x$ is not an integer. Why not $f(x) = \sin(x)$?

Comment: And can I still use the same idea? By that I mean the limits being different.

Comment: If by "divergent function" you mean that the limit as $x \to \infty$ does not exist, then yes, just exhibit two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ such that $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ do not converge to the same number. It should be clear which sequences should be picked.